# Trying to connect Neo4j with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, neo4j

I'm having trouble connecting Neo4j with my ASP.NET Core Web App.
I've installed Neo4j.Driver package, I've added

```
"NeO4jConnectionSettings": {
  "Server": "bolt://localhost:7687",
  "UserName":"neo4j",
  "Password":"<password>"     
  }
```

into appsettings.json. I also have

```
services.AddSingleton(GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "<password>")));
```

in **ConfigureServices** method in **Startup.cs**. In Index.cshtml.cs I am runnning

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly IDriver _driver;

    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    public string result;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IDriver driver)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _driver = driver;
    }

    public async void GetAsync()
    {
        IResultCursor cursor;
        var list = new List<String>();
        IAsyncSession session = _driver.AsyncSession();
        try
        {
            cursor = await session.RunAsync(@"MATCH (a:Movie)
            RETURN a.name as name
            limit 10");
            list = await cursor.ToListAsync(record =>
            record["name"].As<String>());
        }
        finally
        {
            await session.CloseAsync();
        }
        result = list.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

which returns no results.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have trouble connecting or you get no result?

It seems like you're just getting an empty result. Looking at your query, I am pretty sure you're using the default Actors/Movies database set. If so, the `Movie` entity doesn't contain a `name` property. You need to use `title`.

```
try
{
    cursor = await session.RunAsync(@"MATCH (m:Movie)
        RETURN m.title AS title
        LIMIT 10");

    list = await cursor.ToListAsync(record =>
    record["title"].As<String>());
}
```

Also, as you're using **Razor Pages**, if you're using the default convention for method name handling, your `GetAsync` method should be called `OnGetAsync`/`OnGet`.

Comment: No, I've created my own database. Running "MATCH (a:Movie) RETURN a.name as name limit 10" in Neo4j Browser returns the result I want. In the example above I've taken my "result" variable and displayed it using @Model.result in Index.cshtml and it's empty.

Comment: Does the 'list' variable gets populated with any data after you execute the query and exhaust the cursor?

Comment: Also, post the schema of your Movie entity.

Comment: @MilošVeljanovski Check the part about Razor Pages in the answer as well.

Comment: I've just solved the problem. Changed GetAsync into OnGetAsync(). Thank you for your time.